# How to force VideoCall in WebTRC mode using SightCallAPI?

Tags: webrtc, rtcc, sightcall

I'm currently working on a SightCall Proof Of Concept for my clients.
In order to give our clients what they need, I will need access to the HTML video element which SightCall uses to show the call. According to the quick-start example (https://github.com/sightcall/one-to-one-js-sample), it says the window will be placed in the blue box if using webRTC.
I am using Chrome but for some reason a window pops out and seems to be using the RTCC driver instead of WebRTC.

How can I force the call in WebRTC mode instead of using the RTCC driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use WebRTC only, you can add the following property to the options Object before instantiating the Rtcc Object:

```
options = {
    debugLevel : 1,
    displayName : 'Callee',
    container : 'video-container',
    **mode_parameter: 'webrtc_only'**
},
```

This will force the use of WebRTC even if the RtccDriver is installed and running.